# Main thread does not see changes made from background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, realm

I am having troubles trying to see changes made from a background thread, on the main thread.

```
-(void) someMethodRunByBackgroundThread
{
   RLMRealm *defaultRealm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
   MyObject *realmObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];

   [defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction];
   realmObject.myValue = @"Hello World";
   realmObject.primaryKey = 1;
   [defaultRealm addObject:realmObject];
   [defaultRealm commitWriteTransaction];

   NSInteger primaryKey = realmObject.primaryKey;
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
       completionBlock(primaryKey);
   });
}

-(void)completionBlock:(NSInteger)primaryKey
{
    MyObject *realmObject = [[MyObject alloc] objectForPrimaryKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:primaryKey]];
}
```

When my completionBlock gets called, I am unable to find the realm object. Please keep in mind, the completionBlock is dispatched using GCD onto a main thread and according to documentation, the main thread should automatically see write commits done by other threads.

EDIT: I have tried this on Realm 0.98.2 and 0.98.6. I am also currently on XCode 7.3

EDIT 2: Added in the code "[defaultRealm addObject:realmObject];" as I accidentally left it out. Thank you Kishikawa for pointing it out!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `RLMRealm *defaultRealm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm]; [defaultRealm  refresh];` before `objectForPrimaryKey:` in the `completionBlock`? For the investigation.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi Yes that would resolve the problem. I'm guessing there is some sort of timing problem going on with the main thread seeing the changes?

Comment: Yes. In the most cases, the changes reflected main thread immediately. But sometimes not. Because changes notified every run loop. It happens when notification do not meet run loop. It will be delayed next run loop. If you'd like to avoid calling `refresh` method, you should use notification block instead dispatching main thread.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi Alright. If you could please update your answer with this, I will mark it as an answer for my question. Thanks!

Comment: @JasperChan `refresh` fixed it for me as well – thanks @kishikawakatsumi

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not add the `realmObject` instance to the `defaultRealm`. So `realmObject` did not persist to the `defaultRealm`.

To persist an object to the Realm, you need to call `-[RLMRealm addObject:]` method and pass the object that you'd like to persist.

See also https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#adding-objects

```
[defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction];
realmObject.myValue = @"Hello World";
realmObject.primaryKey = 1;
[defaultRealm addObject:realmObject]; // You should add object to Ream to persist the object
[defaultRealm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Comment: Hi Kishikawa Katsumi,

Thank you for pointing that out, but thats merely a typo on my part. I forgot to add that part in in my example code. Will edit it now, thanks!